# Get caret position in non-GDI apps

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, google-chrome, accessibility

So I'm writing an accesibility app that needs to know the location of the text entry caret. I tried GUIThreadInfo, but while that works in basic apps like Notepad, it fails in more complex ones like Chrome, iTunes, etc. that handle their own UI.

*Is there even a way to get the caret position from apps like this?*

Comment: Are you looking for the window handle of the app or the control, or something else altogether?

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I'm in a similar situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doesn't work.  The caret is an implementation detail of user32, associated with a window.  Applications like browsers don't use window controls, far too expensive.  And they don't have to, there's a separate API to allow such programs to provide an interface to accessibility apps like screen readers.  Start [reading here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181208230257/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/active-accessibility-user-interface-services-collision208).  Not easy to use from a C# app, [this project](https://github.com/TestStack/White) can lessen the pain.  No endorsement, never actually used it myself.