# Get caret position from non-GDI apps

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gdi

I know this has been asked before but the answers have not been specific.

[Get caret position in non-GDI apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237960/get-caret-position-in-non-gdi-apps)

I adapted the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application) to C++ and it works well with GDI apps like Microsoft Word, Notepad etc. but it does not work with apps like browsers or text editors (sublime text).

Can anyone give me an example of how this could be done? Is it even possible?

My entire project depends on this feature and without it there is no point to continuing development so this is a critical question for me.

Comment: There are no silver bullet (single way). You should implement cursor position detection for each browser.

Comment: do you know of any examples showing how to do that?

Comment: also I want the caret position not the cursor

Comment: There are a lot of examples in internet. Btw, solution from your link will not work with Qt widgets.

Comment: Please post a relative link. I do not know where to start. And maybe a link describing why it won't work with qt

Comment: Also just for clarification I want to get the caret position from any app from a c++ application

Comment: You can't get caret position for "ANY" application, because "ANY" application may not provide such functionality. It is possible to get caret position for native controls. You already provided a link, how to do it. For non-native controls (browsers) you should research separate solution. One solution per one control. In that position your question is unclear.